# Is there a way to embed my django login form into my base.html template?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I am currently making a django school system, and have come across a dilemma. Whilst I have successfully made a functioning login system, all the tutorials I have seen include a separate page for the login form. Considering that my site is LOGIN ONLY ACCESS, I have an if statement on base.html template that will show content depending if the user is logged in or not. It shows the correct  content if the user is logged in, however, I don't know how to embed my login form into the base.html so I can insert it into the if/else statement. Any easy ways to do this? I'll share my code if needed.

**Current base.html file**

```
  <body>
  {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    THIS CONTENT IS CORRECTLY SHOWING
  {% else %}
   THIS IS MEANT TO BE LOGIN FORM
   <div class="container">
       <form method="post" action='users/login'></form>
       {% csrf_token %}
       <div class="row justify-content-center">
       <div id="login-box" >
       <div class="login-text mb-2" >Login for Access</div>
       {{ form|crispy }}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-2 mb-2">Login</button>
         <br>  <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title=" 
          Please contact your IT Administrator at college for information on how 
          to reset your password">Forgot Password?</a>
        </form>
        </div>
        </div>
   </div>
{% endif %}

  </body>
</html>
```

**What my code is currently showing is below.**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUayI.png

Comment: can you share your code ?

Comment: @Bhupeshlad i just have. please have a look and see if you can help me.

Comment: ive attached a photo displaying my problem, pls try help

Answer (score 0):

in templates you can distinguish the view as follows to separate the views

```
{% if not request.user.is_authenticated %}
SHOW THE CONTENT FOR NOT LOGGED IN USERS
{% else %}
SHOW THE CONTENT FOR LOGGED IN USERS
{% endif %}
```

and your login can be done on base.html file on html form element with action attribute pointing the login url

```
 <form action="{% url 'login' %}" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}

  <input type="text" name="username">
  <input type="password" name="password">
  <input type="submit" value="Login">
  </form>
```

Comment: Ive done that already, but my issue is embedding the login form into the section where you've said SHOW THE CONTENT FOR NOT LOGGED IN USERS. How do I import my functioning login form from login.html into my base template?

Comment: <form action='{% login_url %}'></form>, put it in a form tag with action point to the name of your url and inside it you can add the username and password fields

Comment: The above solution isn't working. My login button is a dead link now for some reason and the form is not even formatting properly. Why?

Comment: ive attached a photo displaying my problem, pls try help

Answer (score 0):

Replace `user.is_athenticated` with `request.user.is_authenticated`

Comment: Okay, that’s fine thank you. But how do I get the login form in the CONTENT NOT SHOWING part ?

Comment: Just add your login forms code in the else block or link your login page to the login button